# Jackson is ignoring spring.jackson.properties in my spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

Jackson is ignoring spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE.
I am using springBootVersion 1.4.2.RELEASE. In my application.properties file, I have added

> spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE

But Jackson is not honoring this property, and my REST response is still camelCase. Interestingly, this annotation works just fine

> @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)

With this annotation, I am getting snake_case response. But I don't want to annotate each response class, it's a bit annoying.

### Edit

I tried using fully qualified class name as well,

> spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy

that did not work either

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had `@EnableWebMvc` annotation in one of the classes (ExceptionHandler) in my Application (face-palm!).

But, as per this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2566),

> If you have @EnableWebMvc annotation, that disables the
>   auto-configuration of Spring MVC, including the configuring of its
>   message converters to customize Jackson's serialization.
>
> It's expected behavior when you use @EnableWebMvc as, by doing so,
>   you're telling Spring Boot that you want to take control of Spring
>   MVC's configuration. That includes configuring its HTTP message
>   converters to (de)serialize JSON in the manner that meets your needs.
>
> If you want to override the Jackson configuration, you can either use
>   the spring.jackson.* properties or, if you want more control, declare
>   your own Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder bean.

Once I removed `@EnableWebMvc` annotation, this property works as expected.

Comment: I have the same problem here, but in my case there's no "@EnableWebMvc" annotation if my code. Any ideas ?

Comment: @Bruno Sorry, I am not aware of any other potential pitfalls; I (or some fellow SOers ) may be able to help if you can add your code base's url, where the issue is reproducible

Comment: @Bruno Did you find the issue?

Comment: Long time ago, don't remember... sorry @ldeck

Comment: @Ideck Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I got this problem, spent the time, fix it and got again over 1 year, and spent time again >_<

Answer (score 4):

According to the doc

```
/**
 * One of the constants on Jackson's PropertyNamingStrategy
 * (CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES). Can also be a fully-qualified class
 * name of a PropertyNamingStrategy subclass.
 */
private String propertyNamingStrategy;
```

You can config it in "application.properties" with this:

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy
```

Answer (score 2):

MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter class uses the default instance created by [Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.html#json--) method. In order to use application conext's ObjectMapper, you can register a custom [WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html).

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcDefaultObjectMapperConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    public WebMvcDefaultObjectMapperConfigurerAdapter(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        // default mapper configured with spring.*
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> httpConverter : converters) {
            if (httpConverter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                // register the configured object mapper to HttpMessageconter
                ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) httpConverter).setObjectMapper(mapper);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe you created class extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` ,`WebMvcConfigurationSupport` contains @EnableWebMvc, do not extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` ,do use some class extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`

Answer (score 1):

Just like @skadya's answer, I update it in new spring version and Java 8 styles.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Autowired  // spring.jackson.* ObjectMapper's config
    public WebConfig(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters (List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.stream()
                .filter(x -> x instanceof  MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
                .forEach(x -> ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) x).setObjectMapper(mapper));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, to solve a similar problem I added this to my application.properties and it worked well:
`spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE`

Note, you don't need to fully qualify the SNAKE_CASE like in other answers

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who stumbles on this thread, I had the same symptom as OP and for my case, it was happening because I'd defined a `@Bean` for a `JsonMapper` (to use on different parts of my code), like this:

```
  @Bean
  fun objectMapper(): JsonMapper {
    return JsonMapper.builder()
      .findAndAddModules()
      .build()
  }
```

The thing that I forgot is that Spring uses Jackson to convert messages. So, in order to fix it, I just had to define a `PropertyNamingStrategies`:

```
  @Bean
  fun objectMapper(): JsonMapper {
    return JsonMapper.builder()
      .findAndAddModules()
      .propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategies.SNAKE_CASE)
      .build()
  }
```